# Don't Apply This Condition PHP(Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Ja_ay' in 'where clause'

This Condition That Not Apply :-

```
               if($count == 1 ){

                $theMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sory The This User Is Exist</div>';
                redirectHome($theMsg,'back');
            }
```

and This My Code

This Variable For Error

```
            $formErrors = array();

            if(strlen($user) < 4 ){
                $formErrors[] = 'Username Cant Be Less Than <strong>4 Characters</strong>';
                $theMsg = '';
                redirectHome($theMsg,'back');
            }
            if(strlen($user) > 20 ){
                $formErrors[] = 'Username Cant Be More Than <strong>4 Characters</strong>';
            }
            if(empty($user)){
                $formErrors[] = 'Username Cant Be <strong>Empty</strong>';
            }
            if(empty($name)){
                $formErrors[] = 'Name Cant Be <strong>Empty</strong>';
            }
            if(empty($email)){
                $formErrors[] = 'Email Cant Be <strong>Empty</strong>';
            }
            foreach($formErrors as $error){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $error .'</div>' ;
            }
```

In This Step I Check If There Any Error

```
            if (empty($formErrors)){
                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username From users WHERE $user = ?");
                $stmt-> execute(array($user));
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

In This Step Don't Apply Condition

```
                if($count == 1 ){
                    $theMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sory The This User Is Exist</div>';
                    redirectHome($theMsg,'back');
                }else{
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                    users(Username, Password, Email, Fullname, Date)VALUES(:user, :pass, :mail, :name,now())");
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                            'user'=>$user,
                            'pass'=>$shapass,
                            'mail'=>$email,
                            'name'=>$name
                        ));
                    $theMsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . $stmt->rowCount() . 'Record Update' .'</div>';
                    redirectHome($theMsg,'back');
                }
                    }
                } else{
                    $theMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger"> Sorry You Cant Browse This Page Directly</div' ;
                    redirectHome($theMsg,'back');
                }
```

Comment: Should `$user` be `username` in the query? Currently your inserting `$user` in a way it is perceived as a column name by the SQL engine. And of course there is no such column as the user name (for most usernames at least). Counts as a typo I guess.

Comment: The error has nothing todo with the code shown, The error is pretty clear, you do a query on a table for a field that doesnt exist. 1054 Unknown column 'Ja_ay' in 'where clause'

Answer (score -1):

Your code here is incorrect :

```
if (empty($formErrors)){
                // replace $user variable with column name in your table
                // here I have just replaced it with 'username' but it depends 
                $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username From users WHERE username = ?");
                $stmt-> execute(array($users));
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: @Grumpy, How this has nothing to do with the error? I mentioned that the problem comes in this snippet of code. He put a variable in the query instead of the column name.